# R's equivalent of string.replace() in python

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation

I need to replace certain values of a character vector:

```
x <- data.frame(Strings = c("one", "two","three","four","five","four","five","four","five","two","thre","two","three","two","three"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> x
   Strings
1      one
2      two
3    three
4     four
5     five
6     four
7     five
8     four
9     five
10     two
11   three
12     two
13   three
14     two
15   three
```

In python, I would do:

```
x["Strings"].replace(["one", "two", "thre","three"], ["One","Two","Three","Three"], inplace=True)
```

But in r the function `replace()` doens't work the same easy-way. There is plenty of solutions for a string replace in Stackoverflow, but no one with this simplicity. Is this possible in r?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution syntactical close to your Python code (using the `plyr` package):

```
x$Strings <- plyr::mapvalues(x$Strings, 
                c("one", "two", "thre","three"),
                c("One","Two","Three","Three")
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you wanted to do is capitalize the first letter of every word, we can use `sub`:

```
x$new <- sub('^([a-z])', '\\U\\1', x$Strings, perl = TRUE)
```

**Output:**

```
   Strings   new
1      one   One
2      two   Two
3    three Three
4     four  Four
5     five  Five
6     four  Four
7     five  Five
8     four  Four
9     five  Five
10     two   Two
11    thre  Thre
12     two   Two
13   three Three
14     two   Two
15   three Three
```

If there is already a list of old and new words for replacement, we can use `str_replace_all`, which has a (kind of) similar style as the python example OP posted:

```
library(stringr)

pattern <- c("one", "two", "thre", "three")
replacements <- c("One", "Two", "Three", "Three")

named_vec <- setNames(replacements, paste0("\\b", pattern, "\\b"))

x$new <- str_replace_all(x$Strings, named_vec)
```

or with `match` or `hashmap`:

```
library(dplyr)

x$new <- coalesce(replacements[match(x$Strings, pattern)], x$new)


library(hashmap)

hash_lookup = hashmap(pattern, replacements)
x$new <- coalesce(hash_lookup[[x$Strings]], x$new)
```

**Output:**

```
   Strings   new
1      one   One
2      two   Two
3    three Three
4     four  four
5     five  five
6     four  four
7     five  five
8     four  four
9     five  five
10     two   Two
11    thre Three
12     two   Two
13   three Three
14     two   Two
15   three Three
```

Answer (score 2):

If capitalization is what you are going for, the package Hmisc with `capitalize()` will work. My apologies if I am misunderstanding the question.

```
library(Hmisc)

x <- data.frame(Strings = c("one", "two","three","four","five","four","five","four","five","two","thre","two","three","two","three"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x<-sub("thre[^[:space:]]*", "Three", x$Strings)

xCap<-capitalize(x)

as.data.frame(xCap)
    xCap
1    One
2    Two
3  Three
4   Four
5   Five
6   Four
7   Five
8   Four
9   Five
10   Two
11 Three
12   Two
13 Three
14   Two
15 Three
```

Thanks to @RuiBarradas in the comments for the sub fix.

Comment: This doesn't correct the typo `"Thre"`, like the OP wants to.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I see, did not read the data carefully enough. I will close this answer, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Don't close it, edit it. After your code, `sub("Thre[^[:space:]]*", "Three", x$Strings)`.

Comment: I need to capitalize, but also I need to replace some specific values (like "Thre" in the example). So thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to just convert them into *factors* and then replace the levels

```
> x <- data.frame(Strings = c("one", "two","three","four","five","four","five","four","five","two","thre","two","three","two","three"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> x$Strings <- as.factor(x$Strings)
> levels(x$Strings) <- c("Five", "Four", "One", "Three", "Three", "Two")
> x
   Strings
1      One
2      Two
3    Three
4     Four
5     Five
6     Four
7     Five
8     Four
9     Five
10     Two
11   Three
12     Two
13   Three
14     Two
15   Three
```

Comment: I am surprised, this was not upvoted more. Any simple solution using just base R is inherently better than the one involving an extra package!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `recode`.  Create a list of key/val pairs, and then use `recode` to match the values in 'Strings' with the 'key' of the `list` and replace it with the corresponding value

```
library(tidyverse)
lst1 <- list(one = "One", two = "Two", three = "Three", four = "Four", five = "Five")
x %>% 
   mutate(Strings  = recode(Strings, !!! lst1))
```

NOTE: Assuming the camelcase is by coincidence

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- data.frame(Strings = c("one", "two","three","four","five","four","five","four","five","two","thre","two","three","two","three"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
y=c("one", "two", "thre","three")
z=c("One","Two","Three","Three")


x$Strings=x%>%rowwise()%>%mutate(Strings=if_else(!is.na(z[match(Strings,y)]),
                                                  z[match(Strings,y)],false=Strings))
```

Using `dplyr()` you would only need to change the `y` and `z`.